# How do i dynamically set the parameter value for selectLink() in Goutte?

Tags: goutte

How to click on a link dynamically using Goutte php web scraping library?  Whatever example that has been shared on net they have only hard coded ('Plugins') the value as in the example below

```
$link = $crawler->selectLink('Plugins')->link();
```

How do i dynamically set the parameter value for selectLink()?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for

```
$text = 'someAnchorText';

$link $crawler->selectLink($text)->link();
```

?